# appengine php imagerotate 90 returns distorted image

Tags: php, google-app-engine

running on the google appengine with php.

if i rotate 180, the page dimensions are unchanged, but if i rotate 90 degrees, the page width grows to page height but the page height remains unchanged and the rectangular image is stretched edge to edge in a page of H x H.

code: imagejpeg(imagerotate(imagecreatefromjpeg($filename),90,0),$filename);

is there a way to get the new page height to shrink to the old page width or to keep the image from stretching to the unchanged image height?

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found that the corruption comes when a different program (FPDF) converts the new JPG to a PDF since it is trying to make it into a Portrait layout.  I'll have to detect and adjust accordingly.